# How to add an activity to tab?

Tags: android, tabs, customization

I have started working the customizing the Tabs in Tablayout, so i followed this tutorial http://joshclemm.com/blog/?p=136 
which works fine. But the doubt is that i cant find out how to add an activity to each tab in this tutorial , i have tried but didnt find the solution.

In general we use

```
    TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Photos");
    spec.setIndicator("Photos");

    Intent photos = new Intent(this, Photos.class);
    spec.setContent(photos);
```

But dont know how to add an activity in this situation.

Can anybody help me get rid of this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[See this example](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
    Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost(); // The activity TabHost
        TabHost.TabSpec spec; // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
        Intent intent; // Reusable Intent for each tab

        // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, DemoActivity1.class);
        // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("todaystake").setIndicator("Todays Take",
                res.getDrawable(R.drawable.icontodaystake)).setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        // Do the same for the other tabs
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, DemoActivity2.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("whatscasting").setIndicator(
                "What's Casting", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.iconwhatscasting))
                .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);
tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
```

your xml file will look something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_above="@android:id/tabs" />
        <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Comment: add this in your main class where you adding your tab host in xml

Comment: Thanks for ur help ,but please check the link i have mentioned in the question and provide me the answer.

Comment: the above code will create tab's with each tab containing a different activity class, its not for creating custom tab

Comment: I wanna customise the tabs , so i have used the source code provided by that link

Comment: give me your mail id, i will send u a customised code that you need

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track - `Photos.class` just needs to be an activity.

See e.g. [this TabActivity](https://github.com/pilhuhn/ZwitscherA/blob/master/src/de/bsd/zwitscher/TabWidget.java#L103) on how I did it with Zwitscher

Comment: Thanks. Did you see the code in that tutorial , can you tell me where to write that in that tutorial code, i am confused... @Heiko Rupp

Answer (score 0):

You just only replace the word **photos** by other name of your name activity class.
But remember that, you must register your activity in androidmanifest file.

Comment: Example I create an activity named test.class
Then I open AndroidManifest, in AndroidManifest.xml Tab, I will add some lines of code like this:
  <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".test" >
        </activity>